# Is it possible to stream android screen to an RTMP server using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, android-ffmpeg, termux, screen-recording

I was wondering if it's possible to stream the android screen using FFmpeg to an RTMP server, what approach to take and if using apps like Termux is enough and hows the command/script would look like.